# Straighten bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

Is there any way to straighten out the default Bezier Curve? By default it looks like this:
[image: Bezier Curve]
What I end up doing is selecting the left control handle and rotating by 45° to make the curve straight. Is there any easier way, a keystroke?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Method one:

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

This flattens the handles on the Y axis (scaling by `0`), however it will distort the rotated handle a little bit:

[image]

## Method two:

<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then  <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>

This sets the handle type to *vector* (which makes connected control vertices straight) and the back to *aligned* (the default).

[image]

Comment: I would set both handles to vector.

Comment: @pinkvertex I would too ;) (and I did, in my gif..). Both handles are selected by default, so I figured it wasn't necessary to include that step.

Comment: Note this only works in Edit mode

Answer (score 7):

To convert a path curve into straight line segments that bend at sharp angles instead of curves when transformed
[image]

Add > curve > path

Switch to Edit mode

On Tool Shelf (left column panel) under Curve Tools click Set Spline Type

Select poly

Comment: This is my favorite way of doing it.